# Magento 2 - Use SKU as condition for Cart Price Rule

Tags: magento2, admin, shopping-cart-price-rules

From this guide - http://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart.html - they describe how to set up cart price rules. I configured these with success. I am wondering, is it possible to use SKU as a condition for the rule to apply? For example, excluding a SKU, or applying only to a list of SKUs

Answer (score 10):

Edit the attribute in the backend and mark the field  `Use for Promo Rules  Conditions` as `true`. After this you should be able to use the SKU as all the other attributes in a promo rule.

Comment: Thanks. Is this a normal thing? Or more of a workaround?

Comment: This is normal. The flag name is called `Use for Promo Rules  Conditions` so its role is to allow certain attributes inside the promo rules.